# CSS Underline using pseudo styles - thickness changes on position change issue

Tags: css, pseudo-class, underline, thickness

I am using CSS Underline using pseudo styles to create underline for text.
And facing an issue of **underline thickness is changed** on changing the position of the CSS property `bottom` on my website.

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.underline:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.underline2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.underline2:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -6px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some example text and this is a <a href="#" class="underline">flashy link</a> using pseudo styles.</p>
<p>This is some example text and this is a <a href="#" class="underline2">flashy link</a> using pseudo styles.</p>
```

If I change value from bottom: -4px; to bottom: -6px; issue start appearing

Link for the same issue
https://codepen.io/Tushar-Jain-the-animator/pen/qBLbyxW

Comment: Do you have any level of zoom on your browser? That's the only time where the underline looks different to me.

Comment: Do the relative thicknesses change when you zoom  in and out? They do for me (Edge/Windows10) so sometimes the top is thicker, sometimes the bottom one is thicker. This can be caused by a sort of rounding error - when the system is trying to map between part CSS pixels and screen pixels (several screen pixels make up a CSS pixel on modern displays).

Comment: @AStombaugh, Yes my screen resolution is 1920*1080 with 125% zoom this is on my laptop's screen and not on Chrome Screen

Comment: @AHaworth, Yes the behavior is same as you are telling "relative thicknesses change when you zoom in and out"